# Faculty Member Enrolling for a Second Degree

Tags: second-degree, professorship

Is it possible for a faculty member (tenure-track) to enroll for a second degree (preferably undergrad in another discipline, but related) while being employed? I know that it should also depend on the institution but are there any ways to minimize the expanses for the tuition?

Comment: Why would a faculty member need some other undergraduate degree? Likely if they ask nicely they could audit courses.

Comment: At least one institution that I'm aware of has a rule against granting degrees to faculty members although they can take courses with a tuition waiver benefit.  Any rule allowing or disallowing this would most likely be specific to that institution.

Comment: @JonCuster Well, it depends on the discipline. I want to get a degree in psychoanalysis which is relevant to my research area but most of the programs require an undergrad degree in psychology so...

Answer (score 1):

In the US, there is often some kind of educational assistance offered as part of the overall benefits package. What is included, and what is restricted, can vary quite a bit so you'll want to check local policies. (It's probably also wise to think through if pursuing a second degree really is a good idea, but I digress.) As a specific example, my current institution rather generously waives tuition for full-time employees (including faculty) for up to nine credit hours per semester (with only minor restrictions related to e.g. executive MBA programs), and discounts it for some family members. Hence it would be possible for faculty members here to pursue a second degree at no cost, but I imagine this fee waiver option is used more often by other categories of employees. In addition to institution-offered assistance, there may also be applicable state laws providing waivers or discounts for employees of public universities.

Comment: Thank you so much for this information. Unfortunately, my institution waives tuition for up to three credit hours per semester which is not very ideal in terms of timing since I have to wait for years to obtain the degree. However, it is not a bad idea to start from somewhere!  I had no idea about these state laws that provide waivers. Is it for US citizens only? I am an international scholar, if so, I may not be eligible. Do you know any specific ones so that  I could start searching?

Comment: @DidemAlkan I'm aware of one such program in Tennessee. It is open to a subset of state employees, and as far as I know, it doesn't have citizenship restrictions. It covers one course per semester, that has to be taken at a state supported institution. But again, whether such opportunities exist is presumably highly location-dependent. If you somehow have the energy and spare time and find three credit hours per semester too slow, you also have all options available to regular students, like attending cheaper institutions, including community colleges.

Comment: This is VERY helpful! I will definitely look into it to see if there is such an opportunity in Louisiana. Thank you so much!